# Creating a guessing game program

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to do a guessing game program in java that spits out random scrambled words stored in an array. It then should check the value to see if it is the same as the user text but it keeps checking the wrong value. I think it is a simple error but I cannot figure out what. Any help is much appreciated.

```
public class GameExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form GameExample
     */
    public int lives = 3;
    public String word2;
    public String word1;
    public String n[] = { "jaav", "ableriva", "todhem", "neergit", "rignst", "loobnea", "loaft", "henceiniret", "loovreading", "yolmropsirphm" };
    public String arr[] = { "java", "variable","method", "integer", "string", "boolean", "float", "inheritence", "overloading","polymorphism" };
    public GameExample() {
        initComponents();


        //Random random = new Random();
        //String val = String.valueOf(n[random.nextInt(n.length)];
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
        String val = String.valueOf(n[i1]);
        word1 = val;
        String val2 = String.valueOf(arr[i1]);
        word2 = val2;


        if(i1==1){
           val = String.valueOf(n[0]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==2){
           val = String.valueOf(n[1]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==3){
           val = String.valueOf(n[2]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==4){
           val = String.valueOf(n[3]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==5){
           val = String.valueOf(n[4]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==6){
           val = String.valueOf(n[5]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==7){
           val = String.valueOf(n[6]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==8){
           val = String.valueOf(n[7]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==9){
           val = String.valueOf(n[8]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

        else if(i1==10){
           val = String.valueOf(n[9]);
            jButton2.setText(val);
        }

    }



    private void jButton2ComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                        

    }                                       
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(lives > 0)
        {
             Random r = new Random();
             int i1 = r.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
             if(i1==1){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[0]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==2){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[1]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==3){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[2]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==4){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[3]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==5){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[4]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==6){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[5]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==7){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[6]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==8){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[7]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==9){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[8]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        else if(i1==10){
           word1 = String.valueOf(n[9]);
            jButton2.setText(word1);
        }

        }

    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       String oneText = jTextPane2.getText();
       String twoText = jTextPane2.getText();

            //jButton2.setText(val2);
       if(oneText.equalsIgnoreCase(word2)){
            jButton3.setText("Correct");
    }else{
           jButton3.setText("Incorrect");
       }
       System.out.println(word2);
       System.out.println(word1);
    }                                        
/*
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    }                                        
*/
    private void jButton4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GameExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane2;
    // End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Nope, too much code. Won't read. Please provide only the relevant code to your specific problem.

Comment: you don't need the if, that's what variables are there for

Comment: Where is the implementation of initComponents() ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your refactored code. Hope it helps you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane2;
    // End of variables declaration

    private static final String CHALLENGES[] = {"jaav", "ableriva", "todhem", "neergit", "rignst", "loobnea", "loaft", "henceiniret", "loovreading", "yolmropsirphm"};
    private static final String ANSWERS[] = {"java", "variable", "method", "integer", "string", "boolean", "float", "inheritence", "overloading", "polymorphism"};

    private final Random random = new Random();

    private int lives = 3;
    private int currentChallenge;

    public GameExample() {
        initComponents();
        nextChallenge();
    }

    private void nextChallenge() {
        currentChallenge = random.nextInt(CHALLENGES.length);
        jButton2.setText(CHALLENGES[currentChallenge]);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // ?
    }

    // never called?
    private void jButton2ComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
        // ?
    }

    // never called?
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (lives > 0) {
            nextChallenge();
        }
    }

    // never called?
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String givenAnswer = jTextPane2.getText();
        if (givenAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(ANSWERS[currentChallenge])) {
            jButton3.setText("Correct");
        } else {
            jButton3.setText("Incorrect");
        }
    }

    // never called?
    private void jButton4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // ?
    }

    public static void main(String args[])  throws Exception {
        validateChallenges();
        setNimbusLookAndFeel();
        startGame();
    }

    private static void validateChallenges() {
        if (CHALLENGES.length != ANSWERS.length) {
            throw new RuntimeException("There must be the same number of CHALLENGES and ANSWERS");
        }
    }

    private static void setNimbusLookAndFeel() throws Exception {
        final String NIMBUS_LOOK_AND_FEEL_NAME = "Nimbus";
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if (NIMBUS_LOOK_AND_FEEL_NAME.equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void startGame() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GameExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Some comments:

Moved all the field declarations to the top, which is standard in Java.

Made fields private, static and/or final as needed.

Removed the logging framework. With a simple application like this you can probably best exit by throwing an exception.

Extracted methods where possible.

Fixed use of Random:
Reused the Random within your class, it is not that cheap to instantiate.
Changed the value passed to nextInt. See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()). Calling random.nextInt(10) gives numbers in the range 0-9. This matches neatly the indices of an array[10]. Convenient, huh? (-:

Renamed fields, methods and variables for clarity.

Collapsed the big redundant conditionals.

Only store the index of the current challenge and use it to look up the challenge or answer when needed.

Added comments for missing or never called code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To get your code working (beside other pending changes) you should replace all the

```
// if i1 is equal to one you don't want to set the label with the
// string from i1-1
if(i1==1){ 
    val = String.valueOf(n[0]);
    jButton2.setText(val);
}
```

by a single line

```
jButton2.setText(n[i1]);
```

In your `jButton4ActionPerformed` you also need to set the value of variable `word2`. if you remove all the other unnecessary lines it might look like.

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
word1 = n[i1];
word2 = arr[i1];
jButton2.setText(word1);
```